# How to use WYSIWYG editor in Phpfox?

Tags: html, css, smarty, phpfox

I am using phpfox cms and it have default tiny_mce editor but i want
to user WYSIWYG editor, please tell me how can i apply WYSIWYG editor
in my code?

I use this code in my controller

```
$this->template()->setEditor();
```

I use this code in HTML

```
{editor id='message'}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

> http://yoursite.com/index.php?do=/admincp/setting/edit/group-id_formatting/

and Change **WYSIWYG Editor** from default to tiny_mce

Answer (score 0):

By default, `phpfox` use normal tiny mce editor. you can use this code to use `WYSIWYG` in `phpfox`

```
{literal}
  <script type='text/javascript'>
     $Behavior.commentPreLoadTinymce = function()
     {l}
         customTinyMCE_init('message');
     {r}
  </script>
{/literal}
```